# UIButton: draw a line below text with x pts spacing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

I need to draw a line below the text in `UIButton`, and I saw some projects having underline inside `UIButton`, by having a view which fits width of the button and stick to its bottom with a height constraint, but that's not actually what I need,  for my case I'm thinking I probably need to know the text's position/size, in order to place the line precisely below the text?

Thanks!

edit:

Sorry I need to note that, I do not need just an underline, what I need is a selection indicator below the title label of the button, say I have to buttons:

**Title1**   Title2

And currently the highlight is below first button's title, when I select the second button I want it to move to below second button's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add border to titleLabel property of UIButton with any spacing.

**Objective-C**

```
CGFloat space = 10;

[_button setNeedsLayout];
[_button layoutIfNeeded];

CALayer *border = [[CALayer alloc] init];
border.backgroundColor = [UIColor  redColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, _button.titleLabel.frame.size.height + space, _button.titleLabel.frame.size.width, 1);
[_button.titleLabel.layer  addSublayer:border];
```

**Swift 3**

```
    let space:CGFloat = 10

    button.setNeedsLayout()
    button.layoutIfNeeded()

    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (button.titleLabel?.frame.size.height)! + space, width: (button.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)!, height: 1)
    button.titleLabel?.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `NSAttributedString`. Attributed string can be used to add an underline or make text bold or any additional attributes. To add an underline to the `UIButton`:

```
NSString *string = @"yo";

NSAttributedString *textString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];

[mainButton setAttributedTitle:textString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't exactly what I need, since I need to do something further with the underline, like animation to another button's label. But thanks anyway!

Comment: You should add that requirement in the issue description.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just change the button title to an attributed string and set the underline attribute:

```
NSDictionary * underlineAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:button.titleLabel.textColor, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:button.titleLabel.text attributes:linkAttributes];            
[button.titleLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Note that you will need to set the text color attribute as well, since the attributed text will not use the button's titleColor by default.

However, if you want more control over the line and its properties (position, length, height, etc), it's going to be somewhat more complicated and likely require subclassing UIButton and overwriting `drawRect`.